# Using Super() Keyword in python

Tags: python, oop

When using a super keyword which is called first Parent or Child element.

I was getting confused in this and was looking for a solution. Like if there is a print statement in the parent class say "hello" and a method in parent class say "hi" and in its child class say there is another print statement say "meow"

will it be hello, hi , meow or meow, hello, hi or hello, meow,hi
please explain why

Comment: Documented here: https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/functions.html?highlight=super#super

Answer (score 1):

Simply put

```
class Parent:
...
   def moew(self): 
      print('Meow')

class Child(Parent):
...
   def moew(self):
      print('Bark')
      super().moew()
```

This will lead to `'Bark\nMeow'`. It all depends on the linear structure.

If you do not define meow in child the parent function will automaticaly be called.

In the child you override the parents function giving it own state (what inheritance is all about).